# Pipelining speed calculations?

Tags: cpu

I'm having trouble finding a formula to calculate this..

The dynamic flow of our program contains 19% branching instructions. The processor uses delayed branching with one delay slot. Calculate how many times the program speeds up, if the compiler can fill the slot 89% of the time.

Calculate the same if there is another slot that the processor can fill in 21% of the cases.

I tried 0.19*0.89+1 for the first one, but an automatic check said that's wrong. I am now out of ideas.

Comment: What equation did you just use above?

Comment: The second part doesn't make any sense. What the heck is "another slot"? Are you asking what is the speedup if another compiler can only fill 21% of the branch delay slots?

Comment: In think another slot refers to the situation that a branch imposes a 2 instructions penalty, so there are 2 branch delay slots after each branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to "find a formula". You need to *think* about what is happening and *write* a formula.

Start by assuming that the branch delay slot is *never* filled. That means that out of every 100 instructions executed in your program, 81 of them run at full speed (requiring 81 cycles), and 19 of them run at half speed (requiring 38 cycles). The 100 instructions require 119 cycles to complete.

If a compiler can fill 89% of the delay slots, that means that 89% of the 19 branch instructions run at full speed instead of half speed. Now how many clock cycles do the 100 instructions require? How much of a speedup is this, compared to the previous case?

Is this enough of a hint to get you going?